# Laravel: How to prevent 'ORDER BY clause is invalid in subqueries' when using pagination in a subquery?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, eloquent, pagination

Laravel: `8.55.0`

SqlSrv: `2017`

I have a query whose basic structure is like this

```
SELECT [main].*
FROM (SELECT TOP 50 [person_view].[person_id]
      FROM [person_view]
      GROUP BY [person_view].[person_id]
      ORDER BY [person_id]
     ) AS [pagination]
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                    FROM [person_view]) AS main
                   ON [pagination].[person_id] = [main].[person_id]
```

I accomplish this query using laravel and pagination on the subquery from (the as pagination query)

```
PersonView::with($eagerLoads)
            ->select($selects)
            ->offset($offset)
            ->limit($limit);
```

Then I add the 'pagination' and 'main' queries together using laravel's `->fromSub` and `->leftJoinSub`

The problem is that when laravel does pagination the 2nd page and onwards uses `row_number()`, and they put it in another subquery like this...

```
SELECT [main].*
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT [person_view].[person_id],
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [person_id]) AS row_num
            FROM [person_view]
            GROUP BY [person_view].[person_id]) AS temp_table
      WHERE row_num BETWEEN 51 AND 100
      ORDER BY row_num) AS [pagination]
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                    FROM [person_view]) AS main
                   ON [pagination].[person_id] = [main].[person_id]
```

Now there is an `ORDER BY row_number` in a subquery which leads to the following sqlserver error...

`ORDER BY clause is invalid in subqueries and views unless TOP, OFFSET, or FOR XML clause is specified`

The docs don't mention this limitation for sqlserver when using pagination.

How can I get around or prevent this?

I was considering somehow removing the `ORDER BY row_num` clause since it's not needed, but I'm not sure how I can do that.

Comment: No idea anything about Laravel, but SQL Server does have `OFFSET/FETCH` so it's weird it's going for a `ROW_NUMBER` instead. Side note: pagination by rows is inefficient anyway, consider using [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)

Comment: @Charlieface I may have to use that, but Laravel doesn't support `OFFSET/FETCH`. Regarding Keyset I believe it doesn't allow you to choose a specific page, only next and previous (see [here](https://www.slideshare.net/MarkusWinand/p2d2-pagination-done-the-postgresql-way/43)). In our case we need to select a specific case.

Comment: Correct, you cannot choose a specific page. But it is far more efficient. Perhaps you can do a manual row-numbering filter

Comment: @Charlieface what do you mean by 'manual row-numbering filter', I'm not imagining how you envision that?

Comment: I don't know Laravel, but perhaps you can get it calculate an actual `ROW_NUMBER` column, and filter that to `BETWEEN 51 AND 100`. In other words, get it to create the same code, just without `ORDER BY`

Comment: @Charlieface Ah I thought that may have been what you meant. If I'm adding in the pagination raw (without using laravel functions) then I can just use `OFFSET/FETCH` the same way.